# unable to persist MEDIUMTEXT type field in spring boot

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have a field named 'value' which is of type MEDIUMTEXT in the MySQL db. When I try to persist or fetch the model, it shows 
`Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction`

### **Model**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "xyz_something")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Xyz {

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 private int id;

 @NotBlank(message = "key is mandatory")
 @Column(columnDefinition = "CHAR")
 @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.CharArrayType")
 private char[] key;

 @Column(columnDefinition = "MEDIUMTEXT")
 @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.TextType")
 private String value;
 // Getters and Setters
```

### **Repository**

```
public interface XyzRepository extends JpaRepository<Xyz, Integer> {
}
```

### **Controller**

```
@RestController()
@RequestMapping("api/v1")
public class XyzController {
    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

    @Autowired
    XyzRepository xyzRepository;


    @PutMapping("/xyz")
    public HttpStatus insertValue(@RequestHeader(value="id") int id, @NotBlank @RequestBody String value) {
        return upsert(value,id);
       return HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;
    }

 private HttpStatus upsert(String value, int id) {
        return xyzRepository.findById(id)
                .map(xyz -> {
                    xyz
                    .setKey("key")
                    .setValue(value);
                    xyzRepository.save(xyz);
                    return HttpStatus.CREATED;
                }).orElseGet(() -> {
                    Xyz xyz = new Xyz();
                    xyz
                    .setId(id)
                    .setKey("key")
                    .setValue(value)
                    xyzRepository.save(xyz);
                    return HttpStatus.CREATED;
                });
    }
}
```

If I comment out the 'setValue(value)' line, it works, else I get an error mentioned above. I have tried using @Lob with columnDefinition = "MEDIUMTEXT". Also, I have tried putting length in the @Column, that doesn't work as well. What is it that I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are using a reserved keyword of MySQL i.e. "key". You need to map it using @Column(name = "\"key\"") above your declaration of the field 'key'. You can refer [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/escape-sql-reserved-keywords-jpa-hibernate/) for more information about reserved keywords.